# Retrieve two sets of data in one looped element

Tags: php, html

I got an owl carousel that shows two testimonials every slide. But the two slides are inside 1 element I want to loop. Every testimonial comes from the database.

So for example I got my loop like this:

```
foreach($array as $testimonial){
    $testimonials .= '
    <div class="testwrapper">
        <div class="testimonial">
            '.$testimonial['title'].'
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial">
            '.$testimonial['title'].'
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

The two titles are each from different testimonials, I figure I have to use their number in the array, but how can I do that? So array value 0,1 on the first slide then 2,3 on the second etc.

Current code after answer by RichardBernards:

```
//  Haal alle referenties/testimonials op
$test               = "SELECT * FROM `web_content` WHERE catid = 12 AND state = 1 ORDER BY ordering";
$testcon            = $conn->query($test);
$testcr             = array();
while ($testcr[]    = $testcon->fetch_array());

for($i = 0; $i <= count($testcr); $i+2) {
    $testimonials .= '
    <div class="reviews">
        <div class="client left">
            <p class="large comment">
                '.$testcr[$i]['title'].'
            </p>
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                    <a href="#fakelink">
                        <img class="avatar media-object " src="assets/images/klanten/sdgsdg.png" alt="avatar" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="media-heading">Name</h5>
                    <p>Bedrijf</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="client right">
            <p class="large comment">
                '.$testcr[$i+1]['title'].'  
            </p>
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                    <a href="#fakelink">
                        <img class="avatar media-object " src="assets/images/klanten/testimonial_foto_sdgdsg.jpg" alt="avatar" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="media-heading">Name</h5>
                    <p>Bedrijf</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
}

echo $testimonials;
```

Comment: maybe using a for-loop?

Comment: why not create a forloop that iterates 2 instead of 1 every loop?

Comment: Your code is wrong. As you are using carousel, and you wrote two div in it, then it will not divide your carousel in two div's it will shows you in the same slider. Rather then putting like this, please create two carousel.

Comment: @KinjalMistry It was an example, the actual code has some different class names and extra divs but it's not relevant.

Comment: @KinjalMistry How can you presume to know how the javascript/css behind this looks like? But even so... When you look at the question closely, you can read "that shows two testimonials every slide"... I think it is meant to be this way...

Comment: @twan Check my answer for an update to make this work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this... Using a for-loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i+=2) {
    $testimonials .= '
    <div class="testwrapper">
        <div class="testimonial">
            '.$array[$i]['title'].'
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial">
            '.$array[$i+1]['title'].'
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 133169626 bytes). Does this code result in an infinite loop?

Comment: only like 10 or so

Comment: @twan Found it... Within the for-loop, at the end it should read `$i+=2`, notice the `=` sign which was missing before...